# Drupal method to retrieve all existing roles and all users of a specified role

Tags: 6, users

I wish to retrieve the list of all users that belong to a particular role.

The query is to know:

- if there's any drupal method that provides list of all available roles created under *Admin >> User Management* (admin/user/roles) similar to retrieving all node types using [node_get_types](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_get_types/6) method.
- if there's a drupal method to get list of all users who belong to a particular role.

Though I could get this done by querying the `role` table and using the result with `user_roles` table, I felt that there might be some in-built method in drupal which must enable me to achieve the desired result which i might've missed out searching.

I'm aware that it's not ideal to check user permission related stuff with roles and rather user permissions instead from [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/check-if-a-user-has-a-role) post.

It'd be great if I could get a definite answer for my above mentioned queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`user_roles()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/6) function to get a list of the roles in the system. You can even pass in specific conditions, for example if you want to get only the roles that contain a certain permission.

As far as getting a list of users by role, there is no such function, unfortunately; you'll have to write a small helper function yourself. I usually use something like this:

```
function users_by_role($role_id) {
  $sql = 'SELECT uid FROM {users_roles} WHERE rid = %d';
  $q = db_query($sql, $role_id);
  $uids = array();
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($q)) {
    $uids[] = $row['uid'];
  }

  return $uids;
}
```

That'll give you the user ids for a given role, after that you can use `user_load()` to get the user object for each, or simply add a join to the above query and include the data you need directly.

Comment: As the query is getting a single field, `db_result()` can be probably be used.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The query's getting multiple results...all of the user ids that are related to a specific role. I think it's very unlikely that there will only be one user per role :)

Comment: `db_result()` returns a single value, but it can be used in a loop; I tried with `$q = db_query('SELECT uid FROM {users_roles}'); while ($uid = db_result($q)) $uids[] = $uid;` and it worked. The fact the function returns the value of a single field doesn't mean it doesn't return the value for different rows.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I didn't know you could do that but it does make sense, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3):

[user_roles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/6) returns an array of roles. There is no function that returns all users of a particular role.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to query a list of users, and filter them by Roles.

Or you can specify an Argument of `User: Roles` on the view. Then use [`user_roles()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/6) in a custom module to grab a list of all roles. Loop through the roles array, and inside the loop use [`views_embed_view('my_users_view', 'display_id', $roleid)`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/6) passing the role id to this function as a third argument.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my query was to know if there was a Drupal method for this without me doing anything other than calling a pre-defined function.