# Can I use the $user global variable for security purposes?

Tags: 7, users

I am developping a module which allows users to modify information about themselves using a form. I want to make sure no user is able to modify the informations about another user. To do this, I thought I could use the uid provided in the `$user` global variable. So my question is: is this safe enough? Or is it somehow possible for `$user->uid` to return something other than the current user's uid? In other words, is it possible to *cheat* the `$user` global object?

This is not the best way to ask this question, feel free to suggest improvements.

edit: Another way of asking this is: Does $user->uid return something different than 0 **only** in the case where the current user has been properly authenticated?

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes, what you describe is how Drupal identifies the active, logged-in user.  Wherever possible, though, you should use API functions such as [user_access('module permission')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) to check access rights, where 'module permission' is a string defined in your module's [hook_permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) function and set for each role on the admin permissions page.

**Edit:** If you want to see if the current user is authenticated, check to see if $user has the authenticated user role.  See [Check if a user has a role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/check-if-a-user-has-a-role)

Comment: If I understand correctly, functions like `user_access('module permission')` check a user's access rights (or rather a role's access rights) to a module. What I need are user access rights to a specific row in a database table (the row with the user's uid as its primary key). This is different, is it not?

Comment: I didn't understand what you were trying to do from your question, but now I see, and yes, you are right. You can assume that $user->uid == 0 for the anonymous user, and if you write $user->uid into a database table, you can be sure that it will uniquely identify that user.

Answer (score 2):

> Or is it somehow possible for `$user->uid` to return something other than the current user's uid?

The user object is initialized in [_drupal_session_read()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/_drupal_session_read/7) using the following code. (`_drupal_session_read()` is a session handler set by Drupal.)

```
// Secure page session.
$user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.ssid = :ssid", array(':ssid' => $sid))->fetchObject();
```

```
// Not secure page session.
$user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.ssid = :ssid", array(':ssid' => $sid))->fetchObject();
```

`$sid` is the session ID.

For authenticated users, the session ID is generated in [drupal_session_regenerate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_regenerate/7) using the following code.

```
$session_id = drupal_hash_base64(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE) . drupal_random_bytes(55));
```

`$user` is initialized to currently logged-in user if:

- `$_COOKIE[session_name()]`, or `$_COOKIE[substr(session_name(), 1)]` is set
- There is a database row in the sessions tables for the current session ID

In the other cases, `$user` is initialized to the object for the anonymous user.