# How do I find the role id from role name?

Tags: 7, users

On log in I want to check a third party data source (table in the db) for a user, and if found I want to add a role to that user.

I don't want to guess the rid of the role, I want to get it from the role name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is quite straightforward with [user_roles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/7) and [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). Below is a function which will return the role ID if there is a role matching the name and FALSE otherwise.

```
function get_role_by_name($name) {
  $roles = user_roles();
  return array_search($name, $roles);
}

// Sample usage
$rid = get_role_by_name('administrator');
```

One liner would be:

```
$rid = array_search('administrator', user_roles());
```

Comment: The query executed by [user_roles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/7) is tagged _translatable_, which means a module could translate the role names. Drupal translates the role names only for the default roles (i.e. anonymous user, and authenticated user).

Answer (score 32):

Knowing the machine name of the role, it is enough to use [`user_role_load_by_name()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_load_by_name/7).

```
if ($role = user_role_load_by_name('Role Name')) {
  // The role ID is in $role->rid.
}
```

If the Role might not exist...

```
$role = user_role_load_by_name('Role Name');

$role_id = $role ? $role->rid : NULL;
```

Comment: I much prefer this approach, as with the other approach the role names could be translated. In fact, the query executed by [user_roles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/7) is tagged _translatable_. Drupal translates only the names for the default roles, but a module could translate the other role names too.

Comment: $rid  = ($role = user_role_load_by_name()) ? $role->rid : NULL;

Answer (score -4):

The best way to identify role and its id is from SQL. Run this query in your SQL editor.

```
select * from roles;
```

And you will get the list of Roles including the id and weight.

Comment: The best way is using the API provided by Drupal. Accessing directly the database, when there is an API, is never a good idea, nor the best way.

Comment: This is a very easy way to get the roles! I'm not surprised the Drupal Stack Exchange Police voted down such a simple solution.

Comment: If all you want is to know the role id you can go to /admin/people/permissions/roles and the role id will be in the url of the role you select.