# Roles Machine name instead of role id

Tags: users

I have custom module code that check the user role and based on user role, user fields updated,

for example

```
if(array_key_exists(12,$user->roles)) {
    //Manger
    $role =  array(8=>8);
} elseif (array_key_exists(13,$user->roles) ) {
    // super Manger
    $role =  array(14=>14);
} elseif (array_key_exists(11,$user->roles)) {
    //section manager 
    $role =  array(14=>14,8=>8);
}
```

so when I want to move this module to other site and import roles using feature, the ids will changed.

so how can I use machine name for roles instead of ids.

Regard,

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50435/how-do-i-find-the-role-id-from-role-name

Comment: I don't want to use role name because it might be changed, also there is different between role name and machine name.

Comment: If you have a look at the role table in the database you'll see that roles only have one name property. So the system name and human readable name are always the same.

Comment: yes, so I asked this question so maybe found other way to avoid using role name and role id.

Answer (score 1):

just make sure when you move your roles that you spell them the same!
then you can use the traditional

```
// Load the currently logged in user.
global $user;

// Check if the user has the 'editor' role.
if (in_array('editor', $user->roles)) {
  // do fancy stuff
}
```

or the more flamboyant

```
function user_has_role($roles) {
    //checks if user has role/roles
    return !!count(array_intersect(is_array($roles)? $roles : array($roles), array_values($GLOBALS['user']->roles)));
};

if (user_has_role(array('moderator', 'administrator'))) {
  // $user is admin or moderator
}
```

see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/check-if-a-user-has-a-role) for more answers to the simple question [Check if a user has a role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/check-if-a-user-has-a-role)

Comment: This is a good approach as roles are hard due to the RID being used for so many things but the RID is an auto increment field. In D8 they have went away from RIDs but it still isn't easy.