# How do I find the role id from an og group role name?

Tags: organic-groups

I need to retrieve the rid to assign the 'student' role part of an **og group**.

I found this post in regards to ***user* roles** [How do I find the role id from role name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50435/how-do-i-find-the-role-id-from-role-name)

```
$rid = array_search('student', user_roles());
og_role_grant('node', $id, $user->uid, $rid);
```

Is there also a function for og group roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a helpful solution using a db query https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/load-drupal-organic-group-role-name

```
$roleid = db_query("SELECT rid, name FROM og_role WHERE gid = :gid and name = :name ORDER BY rid",array(':gid' => 14, 'name' => 'student'))->fetchAssoc();
```

Let me know in case there is any other or better solution, thanks!